# Bootstrap menu and hamburger together

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What is the best way in Bootstrap4 to display a menu AND de hamburger menu together (in a navbar)?
Idea is less important menu elements via hamburger menu.
Thanks for any help!
Gerard

Comment: Thanks for Accepting my answer :) Hope it helped. Do also take a second to upVote.. So that other developers can benefit :) Happy Coding Mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the official bootstrap website. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ , there are a lots of examples of navbar.

The main idea is screen breakpoint. To decide on what breakpoint to show the `hamburger` icon.

In bootstrap-4 this is controlled by the utility class `navbar-expand-X`. So that if we want to show our show our hamburger icon when screen size is medium and below, we will use `navbar-expand-md` on the parent `nav` element.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">...</nav>
```

Bootstrap will give it's own styles for the navbar, which we can then override by our own custom styles based on our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example and try to adapt it on your case:

codepen.io/Plagu33/pen/yoNOJw

Comment: Where is your example?

Comment: Edited.. check now

Comment: Thanks for your help! What I meant was a part of the menu expanded and a part (less frequently used options) as a hamburger. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Hamburger Menu Example**
You can look on getbootstrap.com :

<

```
nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```